# Elasticsearch query - sort by @timestamp and another field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I search elasticsearch (version 2.3) and in the search query sort by more than 1 field?
Right now i'm sorting by @timestamp and I would like to sort by hostname as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) says, you can add one or more sort on specific fields like this:

```
"sort" : [
    { 
        "@timestamp" : "desc" 
    },  
    { 
        "hostname " : "desc" 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "gte": "@timestamp",
                "lte": "@timestamp"
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1000,
    "_source": [
        "@timestamp",
    ],
    "sort": [{
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "age": "desc"
        }
    ]
}
```